# Get multiple values from hash in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
www.domain.com/lookbook.html#look0&product1
```

On page load I would like to grab the whole hash ie. `#look0&product1`
then split it up and save the number of the look ie `0` in a variable called `var look` and the number of the product ie `1` in another variable called `var product`. Not sure how to achieve this.

Is this also the best way of passing and retrieving such parameters? Thanks

Comment: No, you should use `look=0&product=1`

Answer (score 2):

Use `var myHash = location.hash` to get hash part of URL. Than do `var params = myHash.split('&')` and after that for each part do `part.split('=')` to get key-value pairs.

---

Maybe it's better to pass these parameters via GET from PHP side and than post them inside page when page is processed via PHP?

```
<input type="hidden" name="look" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['look']) ? $_GET['look'] : '';?>"/>
```

Comment: @usandfriends I see now... Worst params passing method ever. RegEx than to find number (issue if name is like `param1` and value is textual.

Comment: The op did not mention using PHP. (Not all of us are ;) )

Comment: @nothing9 If you are using such tracking params like product id (??), than you must have database - using some kind of back-end programming language.

Comment: @Justinas No, not necessarily. But nevermind. Your answer gives additional ideas and there is of course no harm in that!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the pure Javascript method:

```
function parseHash(hash) {
  // Remove the first character (i.e. the prepended "#").
  hash = hash.substring(1, hash.length);

  // This is where we will store our properties and values.
  var hashObj = {};

  // Split on the delimiter "&" and for each key/val pair...
  hash.split('&').forEach(function(q) {
    // Get the property by splitting on all numbers and taking the first entry.
    var prop = q.split(/\d/)[0];
    // Get the numerical value by splitting on all non-numbers and taking the last entry.
    var val_raw = q.split(/[^\d]/);
    var val = val_raw[val_raw.length - 1]

    // If the property and key are defined, add the key/val pair to our final object.
    if (typeof prop !== 'undefined' && typeof val !== 'undefined') {
      hashObj[prop] = +val;
    }
  });

  return hashObj;
}
```

Use like:

```
parseHash(window.location.hash /* #book10&id1483 */)
/* returns: Object {book: 10, id: 1483} */
```

I suggest using the norm for passing values through the location's hash: `prop=value`. Ex: `#book=10&id=311`. Then you can easily split on `=` for each property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match(re)` method with use of regular expression to extract the number from the given string.

You can try this:

```
var hashes = location.hash.split('&'); // get the hash and split it to make array
var values = hashes.map(function(hash){ // use .map to iterate and get a new array
    return hash.match(/\d+/)[0]; // returns the numbers from the string.
});
```

```js
var loc = "look0345345345&product1";

var hashes = loc.split('&');

var values = hashes.map(function(hash){ return hash.match(/\d+/)[0]; });

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>'+ JSON.stringify(values) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
var url = 'www.domain.com/lookbook.html#look0&product1'
,   result = {}
,   expr = RegExp(/[#&]([a-zA-z]+)(\d+)/g);
var parts = expr.exec(url);
while(parts != null && parts.length == 3) {
  result[parts[1]] = parts[2];
  parts = expr.exec(url);
}
var look = result['look']
,   product = result['product'];
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'look = ' + look + '<br>' + 'product = ' + product;
```

```html
<p id='result'></p>
```

We are basically using a `regular expression` to divide the parameter name and value into two groups that we can then get by calling `expr.exec(url)`.

Each time we call `expr.exec(url)`, we get the next set of name and value groups.

We set the value of the parameter to its name in the `result object`.

In the regular expression `/[#&]([a-zA-z]+)(\d+)/g`, the `g` after the `/.../` means match **each** time find the two groups.

The two groups are prefaced by either  `&` or `#` (`[#&]`). The first group is a String of letters `([a-zA-z]+)`, the name of the parameter. The second is a String of numbers `(\d+)`, the value you are looking for.

The regex returns the String that matches the pattern as the first result in the `parts` array, followed by the groups matched, which which means that our two groups in each iteration will be `parts[1]` and `parts[2]`.

Comment: I added some explanation @Justinas.

Answer (score 0):

you should use:

```js
function parseHash(hash){
 hash = hash.substring(1, hash.length); //remove first character (#)
 var obj ={}; //create the output
 var qa = hash.split('&'); //split all parameters in an array
 for(var i = 0; i < qa.length; i++){
  var fra1 = qa[i].split('='); //split every parameter into [parameter, value]
  var prop = fra1[0]; 
  var value = fra1[1];
  if(/[0-9]/.test(value) && !isNaN(value)){ //check if is a number
   value = parseInt(value);
  }
  obj[prop] = value; //add the parameter to the value
 }
 return obj;
}


document.querySelector("input.hash").onkeyup = function(){
  console.log( parseHash(document.querySelector("input.hash").value));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="hash"/>
<p class="output"></p>
```

use as

```
parseHash(location.hash /* #look=0&product=1 );
```

/*returns {look: 0, product: 1}*/